# find smallest number divisible by N with sum of digits as N

Tags: java

For a given number N(0<N<=100) find out the minimum positive integer X divisible by N, where the sum of digits of X is equal to N, and X is not equal to N.

```java
public static int getSmallestNumber(int input1) {
    int res =0;
    for(int i=2;i<10000;i++) {
        if(getSum(input1*i) == input1) {
        res = input1*i;
            break;
        }
            
    }
    return res;
}

static int getSum(int n) {    
    int sum = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        sum = sum + n % 10;
        n = n/10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Example: Input: 9
output: 18
Explanation: 1+8 is 9 and 18 is divisible by 9

Example2: Input: 10
output: 190
Explanation: 1+9+0 is 10 and 190 is divisible by 10

My solution works for smaller integer but breaks for larger numbers like 98, 99 or 100.

Comment: "but breaks for" can you explain how it breaks?

Comment: If `N = 90`, then `X` is at least `9999999999` or greater.  But you have only tested up to `90 × 9999 = 899910`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the actual check on the condition `(i % input1 == 0)` to check the divisibility.

```
public static int getSmallestNumber (int input1) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = input1; i < 10000; i++) {
        if (getSum(i) == input1 && i % input1 == 0) {
        res = i;
            break;
        }
            
    }
    return res;
}

static int getSum (int n) {    
    int sum = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        sum = sum + n % 10;
        n = n/10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```